# How do I create release build of my new bitcoin wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, cryptography, c++

I have created a new alt coin, and now I want to create a executable of my wallet in ubuntu. I don't know how to create a release build wallet with all its dependencies. How I can build my wallet application?

Comment: Not sure if you simply forked bitcoin or not, but I believe this will definitely help you out. https://qt-project.org/search/tag/build

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin statically links in all of its dependencies by default, because many of them are consensus-critical and cannot accept a different version. Therefore, you can distribute the binaries that `make` creates.

However, I would recommend setting up [gitian deterministic builds](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/gitian-building.md).